# How to parse a kml file to csv using python/BeautifulSoup or similar?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, gis, kml

I've been trying with limited success to convert a Google Earth KML file to a GIS shapefile (or other GIS file format e.g. Postgresql/PostGIS table) (see - [GIS.stackexchange question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70661/kml-to-shape-qgis-conversion/70667?noredirect=1#comment96281_70667) Essentially I would like to convert the KML file to a CSV.

My problem is that the KML file contains some data stored in an HTML table, so that the parsed KML file has one field in my resulting data table which contains HTML like so:

```
    "<br><br><br>
<table border="1" padding="0">
<tr><td>ID_INT</td><td>NGA0104001</td></tr>
<tr><td>N_sd</td><td>Igbere</td></tr>
<tr><td>Skm2</td><td>3.34</td></tr>
<tr><td>PT2010</td><td>13000</td></tr>"
```

When using the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) library I end up with a CSV file with one of the fields containing a chunk of HTML. I was hoping to use BeautifulSoup (or some similar Python library) to parse the HTML element of the KML file into four separate fields within my CSV file. I seem to be able to pass the KML to BeautifulSoup but am unsure what to do from here, or if indeed there is another way of achieving the same thing.

I have read a bunch of similar questions on this subject here and elsewhere but don't really know where to start parsing this file. Has anyone had any successes with achieving this?? Many, many thanks in advance...

Oh and here's a chunk of code from my KML file as an example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
    <name>AFNGA_SWAC.kml</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin1">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>3</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>3300ffff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin1">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin1</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl1</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl1">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>3</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>3300ffff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>AFNGA_SWAC</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <description>1027 Éléments de la couche Afnga_swac</description>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Aba</name>
            <description><![CDATA[<br><br><br>
    <table border="1" padding="0">
    <tr><td>ID_INT</td><td>NGA0101001</td></tr>
    <tr><td>N_sd</td><td>Aba</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Skm2</td><td>384.07</td></tr>
    <tr><td>PT2010</td><td>1010000</td></tr>]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin1</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            7.294567000000001,5.00267,0 7.294408999999999,5.002552,0 7.294211,5.002394,0
```

Comment: What data do you want to retrieve with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: I'd like to parse these HTML tables which are within the code above: `<description><![CDATA[<br><br><br>
    <table border="1" padding="0">
    <tr><td>ID_INT</td><td>NGA0101001</td></tr>
    <tr><td>N_sd</td><td>Aba</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Skm2</td><td>384.07</td></tr>
    <tr><td>PT2010</td><td>1010000</td></tr>]]></description>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beautiful Soup is usually pretty great at getting straight to what you want (presuming you can easily identify within the xml/html a pattern holding the data you are seeking). I do not know exactly how you want your output formatted, but if you are seeking the data within the `<description>` tags, that's actually pretty easy (examples below are from Python3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

inputfile = "whateveryourfileiscalled.xml"
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

  # After you have a soup object, you can access tags very easily.
  # For instance, you can iterate over and get <description> like so:

  for node in soup.select('description'):
       print(node)
```

Often that's not very useful, so drilling down a bit deeper, we can even access the elements *within* the nodes we find in `<description>`. In addition, we can isolate just the text if we want (using the "string" attribute):

```
  for node in soup.select('description'):
     for item in node.select('td'):
         print(item.string)
```

I always print to test that I'm getting what I want. If there's nothing there, you'll get a lot of `None`s. Anyway, this should get you close and, obviously, instead of printing the output, you can do whatever you want with it (store in some container, write it out to csv, etc.). This would likely work for the chunk you pasted into your comment, but probably not the chunk in your initial question because there you have multiple description tags.

---

In your question, you have more than one `<description>` tag and not all of these have nodes, in which case, you'll need to use find_all instead of select:

```
  for node in soup.find_all('description'):
      for item in node.find_all('td'):
          print(item.string)
```

Comment: thanks for this. Not sure what's going wrong but I'm getting the following errors when I try any of the last three blocks of code above: `In [9]:

    print node

for node in soup.select('description'):

    print node

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/marty/<ipython-input-9-94997d85f5f4> in <module>()
----> 1 for node in soup.select('description'):
      2     print node

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` help?!

Comment: Hmm. It is not finding that `<description>` tag. It works for me using the xml you have. Perhaps you have it indented improperly? Did you try it with `soup.find_all('description')`?

Comment: yep, tried that but got the same TypeError:`In [16]:

          print(item.string)

for node in soup.find_all('description'):

      for item in node.find_all('td'):

          print(item.string)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/marty/<ipython-input-16-0b68b4e99228> in <module>()
----> 1 for node in soup.find_all('description'):
      2       for item in node.find_all('td'):
      3           print(item.string)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: ah ok, it's working now. There was something wrong the bs4 library hadn't been installed properly. I'm now getting this kind of output `ID_INT
NGA3714003
N_sd
Magare
Skm2
1.29
PT2010
10500` This is the data I was looking for! I really need this data output as separate fields/columns in a dataframe(CSV) where 'ID_INT', 'N_sd', 'Skm2', and 'PT2010' are the column headings. I also need the rest of the data that precedes and follows this chunk of HTML parsed as this contains the crucial spatial data (i.e. coordinates) I need to be able to plot this CSV in a GIS. not sure if that makes sense!!?

Comment: incidentally parsing this in BeautifulSoup is killing my machine - is this normal?! to be fair my laptop is fairly old and running a slightly buggy install of Ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: Not sure about that. There's too much here, honestly, to address in comments. Need a new thread, probably. You should try to work it out a bit on your own and then come back to SO with questions.

Comment: You should also mark this thread solved because you now have new questions.